# Containers do not fit inside a big one

Tags: css

The problem is that `#lesson` containers do not fit inside the `#container`. How can I make that only 3 containers fit into one column? CSS ninjas, I need your help :)

[image]
My CSS: `#container` - main container, `#first` - green container, `#lesson`- gray divs.

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    left: 80px;
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
}

#first {
    background-color: #A1D490;
    width:45%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    border:2px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}

.lesson {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #DCDDDE;
    margin:10px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="first">
      <tpl for=".">
        <div class="lesson"; >
          <p class="txt"><b>Lesson:</b> {lesson} </p>
          <p class="txt"><b>Score:</b> {score}</p>
        </div>
      </tpl>
    </div>
    <div id="second">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: it's working for me. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ms92uu9/1/)

Comment: First of all, is there a reason you are using `position: relative` and `float: left`?

Comment: also as you have floated the `#first`. use clear:both to clear the floats.

Comment: @CodeRomeos, i want to make that `only 3 containers fit into one column`.

Comment: Not a big issue. But please consider adding your HTML as well.

Comment: @NicholasRobinson Yes, I want containers to be inlined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fitting the containers on the big one you just need to remove the height 100% from the  id first

```
#first { /* height: 100% */ }
```

Comment: But still new boxes are adding to the bottom, and I want them to add to next column. Is this possible? ( Ex. 3 in a column )

Answer (score 0):

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/dYGLeo

It seems to be working fine for me here. Are you sure you dont have any other css being applied and overwriting rules somewhere?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="first">
    <div class="lesson">
          <p class="txt"><b>Lesson:</b> {lesson} </p>
          <p class="txt"><b>Score:</b> {score}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="lesson">
          <p class="txt"><b>Lesson:</b> {lesson} </p>
          <p class="txt"><b>Score:</b> {score}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="lesson">
          <p class="txt"><b>Lesson:</b> {lesson} </p>
          <p class="txt"><b>Score:</b> {score}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="lesson">
          <p class="txt"><b>Lesson:</b> {lesson} </p>
          <p class="txt"><b>Score:</b> {score}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    left: 80px;
    width:100%;
    height:80%;
}

#first {
    background-color: #A1D490;
    width:45%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    border:2px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}

.lesson {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #DCDDDE;
    margin:10px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Nope, I'm not overriding anything.. In HTML index it's the only one css file despit the bootstrap (but still names are different)

Comment: And this codepen doesn't move to the next column other containers, it just expands the main container/